# How to intercept my phone Number thru Callkit

Tags: swift3, swift4.2

I want to build an IOS App base on swift3 or above. This app is able to intercept my mobile phone number or message thru CallKit and launch the App in the phone.

say, I call my other phone with a message ( Launch Appname : MySillyApp ). when my other iphone receive it, it will launch the app.

Is this possible for CallKit? what other Api available?

-- **Update**

I saw this code but I dont know how it works:

```
import CallKit

final class ProviderDelegate: NSObject, CXCallObserverDelegate { 
var callObserver: CXCallObserver!

func setupCallObserver(){
callObserver = CXCallObserver()
callObserver.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
}

func callObserver(_ callObserver: CXCallObserver, callChanged call: CXCall) {
        if call.hasEnded == true {
            print("CXCallState :Disconnected")
        }
        if call.isOutgoing == true && call.hasConnected == false {
            print("CXCallState :Dialing")
        }
        if call.isOutgoing == false && call.hasConnected == false && call.hasEnded == false {
            print("CXCallState :Incoming")
        }

        if call.hasConnected == true && call.hasEnded == false {

            print("CXCallState : Connected")
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your question is referring to the extraction of a phone number from the regular Cellular call, then it is impossible. You can get call state and UUID from `CXCall` object, but you cannot obtain phone number via any means in iOS. (of course, this is for the regular cellular calls.)

See Apple documentation on `CXCall` **[HERE](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxcall)**

The code that you've shown above responds to any call changes, for example, when call started, when received an incoming call, when call connected and when call ended.

The main purpose of `CXCallObserverDelegate` is to allow application to react to external events, like for example to cancel something the app is doing during the incoming call or something... It is not intended for extracting private information, like calling line's identification.

Comment: yes. This is the scenario. Phone1 call Phone2; Phone2 receive call, then in CallKit receiving event, I want to write code to launch my App in phone2.  Can this be done?